# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "JSON_BUILD_OBJECT" not found

Tags: java, json, postgresql, unit-testing, h2

I'm using h2 db in tests. My test h2 db settings are next:

```
private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
```

I've tried 2.2.220 and 2.1.214 h2 versions.
SQL query is next:

```
        var query = SELECT json_build_object('product', c."info"->'product') as info FROM item."Item" AS c          
    INNER JOIN (SELECT "rootId", MAX("revisionNo") AS maxRevisionNo     FROM item."Item"     WHERE "cRootId" = ?    
 GROUP BY "rootId" ) AS subquery ON c."rootId" = subquery."rootId" AND c."revisionNo" = subquery.maxRevisionNo WHERE c."state" = 'active'
```

I'm trying to create a prepared statement with it:

```
var statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
```

and get error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "JSON_BUILD_OBJECT"
> not found

All works fine with real Postgres db but failed in tests with h2 in Postgres mode.
Can I fix it and how? Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: What leads you to think that H2 has that function? It seems it doesn't

Comment: Your "real db" obviously has that function defined. You need to define it for your test DB. Probably you'll want to enable liquibase (or whatever db change management tool you prefer), and include the changelog that creates the function before executing tests.

Comment: @JohnMitchell no, it's internal postgres function. Seems H2 in PostgreSQL mode doesn't support it

Answer (score 0):

H2 doesn't has the `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT` built-in function. That seems to be a Postgresql function. Either use the same database for test and production or change the query to use H2 `JSON_OBJECT` function (http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#json_object). I recommend the former so your tests match what the application is going to use later.